# ASDoc generation error

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, asdoc

I am following the instructions here for [exporting ASDocs](http://peterelst.com/blog/2009/06/08/flash-builder-4-beta-exporting-asdoc-documentation). The image below is from the tutorial and I have set it up the same.

When I run the configuration I get the error below

```
Loading configuration file /Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 
4.6/sdks/4.6.0 (AIR 14)/frameworks/flex-config.xml

/Users/Steam/Documents/Development/AIR/MediaWindowTest/src/MediaWindow.mxml: 
Error: Unable to locate specified base class 'spark.components.WindowedApplication' 
for component class 'MediaWindow'.
```

So it can't find the base class `spark.components.WindowedApplication` but it *can* find the "flex-config.xml" in the SDK folder. That is what is confusing. The Flex SDK is a copy of 4.6 on which I overlaid the AIR SDK. It works fine to build my project – so I am confused.

Do I need to add another variable to point to the Flex SDK I am using (and why doesn't it pick that up from the project)?

---

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You will also need to add additional arguments as follows:

```
-source-path src
-doc-sources src
-main-title "ASDoc documentation"
-external-library-path+=C:\repository_mvn3\com\adobe\as3corelib\0.93\as3corelib-0.93.swc
-external-library-path+=C:\repository_mvn3\WindowedApplication\bin
```

These will add the external libraries to the build path of ASDoc, but ASDoc will not generate documnetation for them.